# Skip WooCommerce 4.5.x onboarding with WP-CLI

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, wp-cli

I have a bash (.sh) script that I use to install WordPress and install/activate various plugins through WP-CLI commands. Now I want to extend that by installing/activating WooCommerce and setting various wp_options through `wp option set` command.

I want to enter basic stuff (address etc) that is asked in the WooCommerce onboarding setup steps, but in bash. I don't want to deal with the actual onboarding steps in wp-admin.

Already tried:

```
wp option set woocommerce_onboarding_opt_in "yes"
wp option set woocommerce_onboarding_profile "" // aleady tried setting it to serialized data as well
wp option set woocommerce_store_address "street address number"
wp option set woocommerce_store_address_2 ""
wp option set woocommerce_store_city "Mycity"
wp option set woocommerce_store_postcode "1234"
wp option set woocommerce_default_country "BE"
```

But that doesn't seem to be enough. Anyone an idea on how to properly install and configure WooCommerce with WP-CLI without having to deal with the onboarding afterwards in wp-admin?

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure, but maybe you need to install WooCommerce pages?

```sh
wp option set woocommerce_onboarding_opt_in "yes"
wp option set woocommerce_onboarding_profile ""
wp option set woocommerce_store_address "street address number"
wp option set woocommerce_store_address_2 ""
wp option set woocommerce_store_city "Mycity"
wp option set woocommerce_store_postcode "1234"
wp option set woocommerce_default_country "BE"

wp wc --user=admin tool run install_pages
```